# trouble with go stringers exercise

Tags: go, format, printf

For the Stringers exercise in tour of Go:
I got two different outputs for two different format printings. And the only thing I changed was the format verbs. They were %v and %d. Theoretically, they would give the same output. However the output's order was changed too, which was so weird. Any ideas about that? Below is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (a IPAddr)String() string{
    // Here is what I changed
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])
}

func main() {
    addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for n, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
    }
}
```

OutPut:

googleDNS: 8.8.8.8

loopback: 127.0.0.1

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (a IPAddr)String() string{
    // Here is what I changed
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])
}

func main() {
    addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for n, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
    }
}
```

Output:

loopback: 127.0.0.1

googleDNS: 8.8.8.8

The output's order was also changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps are not ordered.

> When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next[1]

[[1]https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.)

I don't see any difference with `%v` and `%d` output other than order.

Comment: Wondering if that rule (order no t guaranteed) is applicable to arrays/slices, which is the case for this exercise. The IPAddress is an array, not a map, right?

Comment: Arrays and Slices are guaranteed to be in order. IPAddr is an array used to represent an IP address, but addrs the thing the OP is looping over is a map

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    
    var s string
    for _, v := range ip {
        s += fmt.Sprint(int(v)) + "."
    }
    sr := s[:len(s)-1]
    return sr
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
   var s string
   for i:= range ip{
     if(i==0){
      s +=fmt.Sprint(int(ip[i]))
     } else{
        s +="."+fmt.Sprint(int(ip[i]))
     }
  }     

  return s
}
func main() {
  hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
    "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
    "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
  }
  for name, ip := range hosts {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some explanation about all that code?

Comment: people are using byte array index to print the values what am did in using for loop for iterate and compute the answer incase the logic was works on more then 4 items in the array

Comment: why `(ip IPAddr)` and not a pointer `(ip *IPAddr)`?

Comment: @cristid9 because function defined on `(ip IPAddr)`, if you change function to `(ip *IPAddr)` and call `fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, &ip)`, it works as you asked.